# php error with $userid, can't retrieve data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session, profile

I am making a profile page that retrieves user info from a mysql database. However I am recieving an error which states 'SQL Error: Unknown column '4'' in 'where clause'' 
Here is my code to define the $userid:

```
<?php 
        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");
        if ($db->connect_errno) {
            echo "Connect failed: " . $db->connect_error;
            exit();
            } 
            $query="SELECT * FROM login_details";
            if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
            while ($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $userid=$row["id"];
            }
            }
            ?>
```

and here is the php for the information that I want to retrieve, I've checked the query on mysql and it works so I think the $userid is not the right value? Or that I messed up using the session code.

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `authors`, `login_profile`, `login_details` WHERE `authors`.`id` = `login_profile`.`author_id` AND `login_profile`.`user_id` = `login_details`.`id` AND `login_details`.`id` = `".$userid."'";
        if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
        while ($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<li>".$row["Bio"]."</li>";
            echo "<li>".$row["Contact"]."</li>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "SQL Error: ". $db->error;
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: You have  a ` instead of single quote in `$userid`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty sorry, didn't see your comment when I was writing my answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thats ok buddy !! Its better to have an answer so that other does not repeat the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a backtick in

```
AND `login_details`.`id` = `".$userid."'
                           ^ right there
```

that should be a single quote

```
AND `login_details`.`id` = '".$userid."'
```

which explains why you are getting the present error.

> SQL Error: Unknown column '4'' in 'where clause

Comment: you are very quick to answer man...!! I just typed the things and you answered... :)

Comment: @HardikBhavsar I used to type at 90 wpm, now am down to about 40 lol that's why I'm fast ;-)

Comment: Thank you for replying! It removed the error but it still won't echo the results. I was wondering if I did the session code correctly?

Comment: @Raru You're welcome. `<li>` is usually associated with an accompanying `<ul>` which isn't in your code. Could be a contributing factor. But this type of query may require using a JOIN. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Raru Plus, are those 2 bodies of code inside seperate files or inside the same one? If inside the same one, then put your query inside the loop. Add error checking to your query rather than in the `else`.

Comment: What's JOIN if you don't mind me asking? No errors show up but I've changed the `$userid=$row["id"]` to `$userid =1` and it works. So I think the problem is that I haven't defined the $userid correctly.

Comment: @Raru this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins demonstrates how JOINS work.